# Is variable when accessed from outside the For loop is not possible in Java if declaration is done in main method & initialization inside loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-errors, initialization, declaration

```
class Myclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x; // Declared in main method

        if (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                x = 5;// initialized inside loop
            }
        }

        System.out.println(x);// accessing outside for loop
    }
}
```

This gives an error: variable x might not have been initialized
            System.out.println(x);
                               ^
1 error;

However, below code working fine

```
class Myclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x; // Declared in main method

        if (true) {
            x = 5;// initialized in if block
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                // x=5;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(x);// accessing outside if loop
    }
}
```

Here in both the code, the only difference is that in 1st case, the variable is initialized in "for loop" while in 2nd case it is initialized in "if block". then why it is making difference. Kindly explain to me as I am not able to find the real reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know that`x` *will* be initialized when you access it. That's because the compiler doesn't check whether the loop body will actually be executed (there might be rare cases where even such a simple loop might not run).

The same would be true for your if-block if the condition wouldn't be always true, i.e. if you'd use a boolean variable like this:

```
int x;

boolean cond = true;
if( cond ) {
  x = 5;
}

//The compiler will complain here as well, as it is not guaranteed that "x = 5" will run
System.out.println(x);
```

You as a human would say "but `cond` is initialized to `true` and will never change" but the compiler doesn't know for sure (e.g. because of possible threading issues) and thus it will complain. If you'd make `cond` a final variable then the compiler would know that `cond` would not be allowed to change after initialization and thus the compiler can inline the code to effectively have `if(true)` again.

Answer (score 0):

It is accessible still there is a chance that the program will never access the for block. Since compiler does not meet any other initialization of the var outside the for loop it gives you an error. In order to compile it you have to initialize the variable with a default value :

```
class Myclass {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int x = 0; // Declared in main method and init with a default value.

        if(true) {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
                x=5;// Reinitialized inside loop
            }
        }
        System.out.println(x); // No problems here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

public static void main (String[] args)
    {

```
     int x; // Declared in main method

    if(true)
    {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
       {
           x=5;// initialized inside loop


       }

    }
    System.out.println(x);//accessing outside for loop
}
```

`x` will only be set if the loop runs. The compiler considers it a possibility that that will never happen.

In the other case: `if(true)` the compiler recognizes as "This will happen"

If you want to avoid this, change

```
int x;
```

to

```
int x = 0; // or use another default variable
```

Comment: In general, be very careful when initializing a variable to some arbitrary value just because the compiler complains - it might be actually right (not in this simple case obviously).

Comment: @JiriTousek keeping code impossible to compile doesn't really improve the case

Comment: Trying to understand why the compiler complains and find a possible flaw in one's design might improve the case, though. Cases like the OP's where the initialization is guaranteed are rare IMO. Either you have a good reason to initialize it and a reasonable default to initialize to, or should rewrite the code in a way that doesn't rely on initialization to a number that doesn't make sense. Skipping this thought process and just using a random number seems dangerous to me.

Comment: @JiriTousek I never suggested to use a "random number". I've never encountered any usecase in which there was not (at least) one default value, if only for the "did not find" scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the condition in the if block from `true` to `false` you would get the same error that `variable 'x' might not have been initialized`. When you do `if(true)` the compiler can understand that the code inside if block will always run and hence the variable x would always be initialized.

But when you initialize the variable inside the for loop, it may happen that the for loop is never run and variable is left uninitialized.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

      int x; // Declared in main method
         if(false)
            {
                x=5; //compile error
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                {
                    //x=5 initialized inside loop
                }

            }
            System.out.println(x);
        }
```

To avoid this scenario initialize the variable as `int x = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

In java `for` loop evaluated at run-time so compiler ignores check for variable initialization inside loop, that is the reason "x" have to initialized with value.